# Python pandas: if column A value appears more than once, assign first value of column B

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, conditional-statements, mapping

I am trying to dynamically replace the value *i* of **column B** with a consistent value conditional on the value count of *j* in **column A**.

I'm trying to use a dictionary to map the values, but it isn't working.

```
color = ['black','mauve','teal','green','teal','black']
code = ['E45', 'M46', 'Y76', 'G44', 'T76','B43']

df = pd.DataFrame({'color': color, 'code': code})

# Dedupe a copy
df_copy = df
df_copy = df_copy.drop_duplicates(subset='color', keep='first')

# Create a dictionary
dummy_dict = df_copy[['color','code']].to_dict('list')
# {'color': ['black', 'mauve', 'teal', 'green', 'teal', 'black'], 'code': ['E45', 'M46', 'Y76', 'G44', 'T76', 'B43']}

### Not working
df["new_code"] = df.code.replace(dummy_dict)

### Output (wrong):
# color   code   new_code
# black    E45   E45
# mauve    M46   M46
# teal     Y76   Y76
# green    G44   G44
# teal     T76   T76
# black    B43   B43


### Desired output:
# color   code   new_code
# black    E45   E45
# mauve    M46   M46
# teal     Y76   Y76
# green    G44   G44
# teal     T76   Y76
# black    B43   E45
```

Where am I going wrong? It's as though Python isn't even accessing my dictionary to map the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `transform` and `first`

```
df['new_code'] = df.groupby('color').code.transform('first')

Out[21]:
   color code new_code
0  black  E45      E45
1  mauve  M46      M46
2   teal  Y76      Y76
3  green  G44      G44
4   teal  T76      Y76
5  black  B43      E45
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant answer than the one I just published- I'll accept it momentarily. Thanks Andy.

Comment: @LindsayVeazey: you're welcome. Glad I could help :)